# Using string interpolation inside an external template resource

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm refactoring an Angular 2 component that does some template nesting.

The original code was something like this:

(component.ts)

```
let subItemTemplate = require('./sub-item-template.html');

@Component({
selector: 'my-component',
template: `
  <div *ngIf="isSingle">
    ${subItemTemplate}
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isMulti">
    ${subItemTemplate}
  </div>
`
})
export default class MyComponent{
}
```

With an inline template, this works great - the string interpolation for my subItemTemplate is successfully parsed and my component works.

When I move the component template into an external file, this stops working:

```
let subItemTemplate = require('./sub-item-template.html');

@Component({
selector: 'my-component',
template: require('./my.component.html')
})
export default class MyComponent{
}
```

Now I get a runtime exception in my browser:

> zone.min.js:1 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your
>   template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("

The only change is from moving my template to an external file.

I'm thinking this can be one of 2 major issues. Either it's an Angular limitation I'm not understanding, or Angular is a red herring and this is actually an issue in my compilation scripts (ultimately bundling with browserify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to do the wrong way.

In the first way, you write template via string and import sub-template like a string. With string interpolation, you concat. template with sub-template, and then Angular 2 parse the result when you load the component.

In the second way, your template is import and served to Angular 2. But sub-template is alone and never used/concat.

**Why you need to add a sub-template in your component ?**

Because the sub-template is requiered in this component ?

So, make a sub-component with template, and use it your parent component, it's readable and easy.

If you need to pass data or event, check @Input and @Output decorator.

If you really need to add a sub-template, they've many way to do this like @ViewChild. Check Angular 2 documentation.

Comment: I agree - thanks for explaining how the template construction works. For my question, the sub-template import was done only to prevent duplication of the code in 2 places of the main template. I've moved that template into a standalone sub-component and not only does it work correctly, it actually *looks* like a sane ng2 component now.